When to use geometric distribution in dice rolling problems
I am trying to practice solving dice problems but am finding myself overusing the geometric distribution. My understanding is that it can be used to model the number of iid trails until "success."
Concretely, I was working on solving this problem:

Suppose n six-sided dice are rolled and summed. For each six that appears, we sum the six, and reroll
that die and sum, and continue to reroll and sum until we roll something other than a six with that die.
What is the expected value of the sum? What is the distribution of the sum?

My approach was to let the sum be Z and the amount contributed to the sum from each dice be $X_j$, where $X_j = 6\times N_j+Y_j$. For $N_j\sim Geom(\frac{5}{6})$ and $Y_j\sim Dice(5)$. Logically, I thought about this as the amount contributed to the sum is equal to the number of sixes you roll (times 6), which I thought would be $Geom(\frac{5}{6})$, plus the final roll of less than 6. In expectation, this would end up being $E[Z]=10.2n$, which is much larger than the correct answer.
If I had to guess, I would say that the issue is with the independence (or rather lack thereof) of the $N_j$ and $Y_j$; however, I don't see how the number of times you roll 6 could give information about the next roll or vice versa. I fear I may be misunderstanding something about the geometric distribution's use-cases. Thanks in advance!

So you should have $E[X_j]=6E[N_j]+E[Y_j]$. What did you get for $E[N_j]$ and $E[Y_j]$, and why?

Your expression

$X_j=6\times N_j+Y_j$ for $N_j\sim\mathrm{Geom}(5/6)$ and $Y_j\sim\mathrm{Dice}(5)$

is correct. However, you should then get
$$\mathbb{E}(X_j)=6\mathbb{E}(N_j)+\mathbb{E}(Y_j)=6\times \frac{1}{5}+3=4.2.$$
The problem is with the definition of $\mathrm{Geom}(\theta)$. There are two different definitions: one counts the number of failures before a success, so takes values $0,1,2,\ldots$, whereas the other counts the total number of rolls including the success, taking values $1,2,3,\ldots$
In your expression above, you need the first of these; however, you must have used the formula for expectation of the second. That is why you are out by exactly $6$, for the one extra roll. (The first version has expectation $\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}$).

In general, a geometric distribution is most appropriate for dice rolls where:

The result of each die directly affect the number of dice thrown
The result of each die is a binary choice, either "success" or "not success".
Only 1 die is thrown.

If you're throwing the same number of dice regardless of what the results of the dice are, then you likely are not looking a a geometric distribution. If any given outcome of each die could result in a range of numeric values, then you are likely not looking at a geometric distribution. If you are throwing more than one dice, you are not technically looking at a geometric distibution - instead you're looking at a negative binomial distribution, the generalization of the geometric distribution.
In this case, you're actually pretty close here - there is a single outcome that results in us throwing another dice, and another outcome that "terminates" each die roll (in this case, that terminating outcome results in us then assigning that die into five possible value outcomes). However, we aren't throwing just one die - instead, we're throwing an arbitrary number. This means that we're looking at a negative binomial distribution, with our terminating rolls using a standard dice distribution. So, we can find the expected value of the roll by splitting the expectation into the expectation of our rerolls, and the expectation of our terminating rolls.
That first scenario is a negative binomial distribution - it's the number of rerolls times the value of the reroll (6, in this case). The formula for determining the expected number of rerolls before we reach $n$ terminating outcomes (1 for each die - once we terminate we can no longer roll that die) is:
$$E(\text{# rerolls})=\frac{n(1-p)}{p}$$
where $p$ is our probability of terminating for each throw. We know that's $\frac{5}{6}$, and the value of each reroll is $6$ so we can sub those in:
\begin{align*}E(\text{value of rerolls})&=\frac{6n(\frac{1}{6})}{\frac{5}{6}}\\
&=\frac{6n}{5}
\end{align*}
The next step is to figure out the expectation of our terminating condition. In effect, this condition is simply the expectation of the sum of $n$ 5-sided dice (since the terminating rolls cannot, by definition, contain a 6). We know that an $d$-sided die has an expected value of $\frac{d+1}{2}$, so a 5-sided dice has an expected value of $\frac{5+1}{2}=3$, and thanks to the linearity of expectation, we can simply multiply that by $n$, so $3n$ is the expected value of the terminating rolls. Now, we just sum our two expectations to get the total expectation:
$$E(X)=\frac{6n}{5}+3n = \frac{21n}{5} = 4\frac{1}{5}n$$
To find the distribution of the sum, again, we can break it down into a mass function for the rerolls, and a mass function for the terminating rolls.
The mass function for the number of rerolls is very straightforward, as the negative binomial distribution has a very straightforward mass function:
$$P(X=x)=\binom{n+x-1}{x}\left ( 1-p \right )^{x}\left ( p \right )^{n}$$
where $n$ is the number of dice, $p$ is the terminating probability, and $x$ is the number of rerolls. The mass function for the terminating dice roll is more complicated, but we can borrow the one in that link for our purposes:
$$P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{d^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{y-n}{d}\right \rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{y-dk-1}{n-1}$$
where $d$ is the number of side, $n$ is the number of dice, and $y$ is the sum we're finding the probability for. Functionally, the mass function we want is going to be the product of these two mass functions, however there will likely be more than one combination of rolls that results in a given sum, so we need to make sure we sum all the possible options.
Let's define $z$ as the sum we're looking for. we know that:
$$z = 6x+y$$
Since we only have two variables, we should be able to get away with a single additional sum, so let's set an iterating variable, $j$ to $x$ and define $y$ in terms of our desired total and $j$:
$$z = 6j+y$$
$$y = z-6j$$
With that, we should be able sub in our values and build our PMF:
$$P(X+Y=z)= \sum_{j=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{z}{6}\right \rfloor}\binom{n+j-1}{j}\left ( \frac{1}{6} \right )^{j}\left ( \frac{5}{6} \right )^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{5^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{z-6j-n}{5}\right \rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{z-6j-5k-1}{n-1}$$
A final edit, I've gone ahead and implemented this formula in Excel and produced a chart of $n=1$ through to $n=5$ so we can see the distribution curves:

